# Query URI service and return value to form field

Tags: forms, uri

I would like to have a form field that when filled returns the information that the specific company name is available for registration or not. I have checked companies house website and they have their URI service, but it looks like that the query should be made by company number and not by name:
http://business.data.gov.uk/id/company/{companynumber}

[Companies house](http://www.companieshouse.gov.uk/about/miscellaneous/URI.shtml)

I'm newbie, so if with any answer you can provide me any code example that would be great, thanks in advance.